# Should we use cin.ignore() in competitive programming?

Tags: c++, cin

The inputs are an integer followed by two strings.

I want to write the following code

```
cin>>num;
cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
getline(cin,string1,'\n');
getline(cin,string2,'\n');
```

If I omit line 2, the code fails on my compiler. I don't know how an online judge works. Is the cin.ignore() function required? Are the delimiters '\n' required as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the cin.ignore() function required?

Yes, otherwise the first `getline` will get the (perhaps empty) remainder of the line containing the first number.

> Are the delimiters '\n' required as well?

Yes, by default it will ignore all characters including end-of-line. Specify `\n` to ignore all characters up to (and including) the end of the current line.

Comment: I got the following compilation error in CodeChef

`int main()': prog.cpp:23: error: 'numeric_limits' was not declared in this scope prog.cpp:23: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token prog.cpp:23: error: no matching function for call to 'max()`

The code runs on CodeBlocks. What is the error then?

Comment: @user2441151 `numeric_limits` is defined in the header `<limits>`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that for a moment, but it was working in CodeBlocks without the header file. Compiles on CodeChef now :)

Answer (score -1):

This is something I just discovered today so I am here to share this with you.

When you take inputs for numeric values use

```
cin>>numberVar>>ws;
```

This will avoid white spaces and will let you use

```
getline(cin, stringVar);
```

Without any problems.

Happy to Help.